# How to navigate recursively in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

```
I am new to XSLT script. I have the input is like as follows:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<FileDescriptorSet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <file>
    <FileDescriptorProto>
      <name>Message</name>
      <dependency />
      <message_type>  

        <DescriptorProto>
          <name>ABCD</name>
          <field>
            <FieldDescriptorProto>
              <name>Type</name>
              <number>10</number>
              <type>TYPE_STRING</type>
            </FieldDescriptorProto>
            <FieldDescriptorProto>
              <name>List</name>
              <number>20</number>
              <type>TYPE_STRING</type>
            </FieldDescriptorProto>
          </field>         
        </DescriptorProto>

        <DescriptorProto>
          <name>XYZ</name>
          <field>
            <FieldDescriptorProto>
              <name>Instance</name>
              <number>1</number>              
              **<type>ABCD</type>**
            </FieldDescriptorProto>
          </field>
        </DescriptorProto>

      </message_type>
    </FileDescriptorProto>
  </file>
</FileDescriptorSet>
```

In the above example it has 2 DescriptorProto namely ABCD and XYZ. 
The second DescriptorProto XYZ has reference to the first DescriptorProto (ABCD). 
My question is how to navigate to the ABCD when i encounter the reference in XYZ (marked ** in the above code).

Basically i want to extract the defnition of ABCD when i encounter the **ABCD** reference in the XYZ. The expected output like:

Under XYZ:

```
--Instance
--1
--Type
--10
--TYPE_STRING
--List
--20
--TYPE_STRING
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following XSLT generates the desired output by using a recursively called template. The initial call is done by explicitly selecting the type given by name `XYZ`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <!-- explicitly call for the initial type -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//DescriptorProto[name='XYZ']" mode="dump"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- recursively handling -->

  <xsl:template match="DescriptorProto" mode="dump">
    <xsl:for-each select="field/FieldDescriptorProto">
      <xsl:text>--</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>--</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="number"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:variable name="type_name" select="type"/>
      <xsl:choose>        
        <xsl:when test="//DescriptorProto[name = $type_name]">
          <!-- recurse using the type name -->
          <xsl:apply-templates select="//DescriptorProto[name = $type_name]" mode="dump"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <!-- no further recursion possible (due to base type); just output the type name -->
          <xsl:text>--</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$type_name"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you Marcus Rickert for your prompt reply. Will this work for all cases i.e., assume the descriptoproto names (ABCD, XYZ) is not known it might be anything (STACK, OVERFLOW) in that case also will it work with out changing the above code?. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Well, in this version you will have to change the constant `'XYZ'` accordingly. You may consider passing the string as a paramter to the XLST process. Of course, you can also iterate over several initial prototypes. In this you probably want to change the output slightly to seperate the output for the individual prototypes.